# Apps disappeared from start screen Lumia 640xl updated to win10

Tags: windows-10-mobile, lumia, apps, screen

Weeks ago I had arranged the tiles on my start screen with all the apps and shortcuts I require the most. Yesterday morning the start screen looked totally different like, empty spaces between the tiles, tile sizes changed and worst of all half of the apps were missing. Not only the downloaded apps but even my phone camera icon was gone! Also after swiping from right to left the list of apps was quite decimated. I made a restart, but to no avail. Opening the back cover, taking out the battery and restarting again was unsuccessful too. What is funny, one app called "Alarms&clocks" which was before also pinned to start screen, was still in the "All apps" list but when pressed longer the message "pin to start" didn't react. Then I went to the store and wanted to download WhatsApp again. But surprise, the message came that this app is already installed. I went to "All Settings" and opened "Apps" and then "Apps&features" and all the apps were there.
So my questions are:
1.) how do I get them back to the start screen, because if I press on an app icon the options are only "Move" (=saving either on the phone or SD card) or "Uninstall".
2.) Why did it happen at all and how can I avoid it in future?
Thanks in advance 
Joachim